# Symfony2 Twig overriding default path function

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I need a way to override the basic path() function in twig.

I have a twig extension already, but defining a path filter there did not do the trick for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Extend the default routing extension class.

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\RoutingExtension;

class MyRoutingExtension extends RoutingExtension
{
    public function getPath($name, $parameters = array(), $relative = false)
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```

Then specify your class using a parameter:

```
parameters:
    twig.extension.routing.class: MyNamespace\MyRoutingExtension
```

======================================================================

To inject more dependencies such as the domain you basically need to copy the service definition and then add your stuff:

```
# services.yml
twig.extension.routing:
    class: '%twig.extension.routing.class%'
    public: false
    arguments: 
      - '@router'
      - 'domain'

class MyRoutingExtension extends RoutingExtension
{
    protected $domain;

    public function __construct($router,$domain)
    {
        parent::__construct($router);

        $this->domain = $domain;
    }
}
```

You could also add the argument to the service definition from inside of your DependencyInjection extension.  That might be a bit more robust that copying the service definition.  There is always the risk that the definition might change if symfony is updated.  Unlikely.  I don't happen to have an example handy.

By the way, you should probably avoid adding a question to an existing question.  Some of the down voters will take a dim view.

Comment: Excellent, just what I need.
An additional question, if you don't mind: how can I inject the current domain here?

Comment: Updated answer to show how to inject additional information.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of that. I must be exhausted. Thanks man.