# How to generate routes ignoring extra passed parameters

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-2.5, symfony-routing

Lets say that i have the following route annotations for a controller action:

```
* @Route("/post/{post_id}/", name="post.view")
* @Route("/post/", name="post.current_view")
```

And I want to use twig to generate the url for this:

```
{{ url(basePath~'view', {'post_id':post.postId}) }}
//basePath will either be "post." or "post.current_"
```

What i currently get is:

```
domain.com/post/1/
domain.com/post/?post_id=1
```

What i want though is for the second route to be generated ignoring any "EXTRA" parameters passed to it so that i would only get:

```
domain.com/post/
```

Does anyone know if this is something that can be natively accomplished? I know i could right a custom twig function that uses the router and then i can generate the routes and strip the query string but i want to avoid that if there is an easy toggle somewhere that i have missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution #1** you could just add an if clause

```
{% if BasePath == 'post.' %}
    {{ url(BasePath~'view', {'post_id':post.postId}) }}
{% elseif BasePath == 'post.current_' %}
    {{ url(BasePath~'view') }}
{% endif %}
```

maybe not the most elegant but should work.

**Solution #2**

spliting url with question marks and getting the first string

```
{% set myUrl = url(basePath~'view', {'post_id':post.postId}) %}
{{ myUrl|split("?")|first }}
```

**Solution #3** Or you can override the url function by extending RoutingExtension class of twig.

```
Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\RoutingExtension
```

can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23958147/symfony2-twig-overriding-default-path-function) with `path` but `url` should be the same.

You should override this function

```
 public function getUrl($name, $parameters = array(), $schemeRelative = false)
    {
        return $this->generator->generate($name, $parameters, $schemeRelative ? UrlGeneratorInterface::NETWORK_PATH : UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);
    }
```

your function could look like this:

```
public function getUrl($name, $parameters = array(), $schemeRelative = false)
{
   $yourUrl = parent::getUrl($name, $parameters = array(), $schemeRelative = false);
   return strstr($yourUrl, '?' , true);
}
```

what id oes it removes everything afther the question mark.

To override the default class you have to add to the parameters

```
twig.extension.routing.class: MyNamespace\MyRoutingExtension
```

Comment: Not a fan of adding if statements all over the place, but adding `|slit('?')|first` to the end of the links isnt too bad

Answer (score 0):

I guess not, you need a preg_replace filter and this isn't natively defined