# How to override twig native functions?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I would like to override twig functions `include` and `extend`.

The reason is that my bundle provides several compleatly different **themes**, but the file names and tree structure are always the same.

E.g. when theme is set to **bootstrap** and required file name is `@ACMEBundle/index.html.twig` it should be transformed to `@ACMEBundle/theme_bootstrap/index.html.twig`

If theme is 'ui' then  final name is `@ACMEBundle/theme_ui/index.html.twig`.

I see here 2 solutions:

1. override completely `extends` and `include` in order that i use it like `{% '@ACMEBundle/index.html.twig' %}`
2. create new `extends_theme_aware` and `include_theme_aware` functions which transform template's name and use native functions to do the job.

How can I acheive this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23958147/symfony2-twig-overriding-default-path-function it may help you

Comment: Why not make a variable for `theme_bootstrap` and `theme_ui` ? something like `@ACMEBundle/'~ var_theme ~'/index.html.twig`

Comment: OK, this solution fits