# Twig null date filter shows current date

Tags: symfony, date, twig

According to the documentation

> If the value passed to the date filter is null, it will return the
>   current date by default. If an empty string is desired instead of the
>   current date, use a ternary operator:

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/date.html

The problem is the solution provided entails that we revisit all dates in the application and apply the ternary operation as we never want to show today's date instead of null.

is it possible to override the default date filter? if so how can I implement this. We're using twigs with symfony 2.7

Comment: Yes you can, take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23958147/symfony2-twig-overriding-default-path-function

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As explained [here in the doc](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/advanced.html#overloading), you can override an existing filter:

> To overload an already defined filter, test, operator, global
>   variable, or function, re-define it in an extension and register it as
>   late as possible (order matters).

Here is the code to return an empty string instead of the current date if `null`:

```
class DateEmptyIfNull extends Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new Twig_Filter('date', array($this, 'dateFilter')),
        );
    }

    public function dateFilter($timestamp, $format = 'F j, Y H:i')
    {
        $result = '';
        if($timestamp !== null)
        {
            $result = parent::dateFilter($timestamp, $format);
        }
        return $result;
    }
}

$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addExtension(new DateEmptyIfNull());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just had to modify it a bit to fit my symfony solution by adding $result = date($timestamp->format('Y-m-d H:i')); and / before class names

Comment: whats the difference between Twig_Filter and Twig_SimpleFilter class?

Answer (score 9):

From the documentation:

*If the value passed to the date filter is null, it will return the current date by default. If an empty string is desired instead of the current date, use a ternary operator:*

```
{{ post.published_at is empty ? "" : post.published_at|date("m/d/Y") }}
```

You can check it at https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/date.html

Answer (score 3):

Here's the Twig 3.0 solution

Extension class:

```
namespace Application\Twig\Extensions;

use Twig\Environment;
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFilter;

class DateWithFallback extends AbstractExtension
{
    /**
     * @var Environment
     */
    protected $twig;

    /**
     * DateWithFallback constructor.
     *
     * @param Environment $twig
     */
    public function __construct(Environment $twig)
    {
        $this->twig = $twig;
    }

    /**
     * @return array|TwigFilter[]
     */
    public function getFilters(): array
    {
        return [
            new TwigFilter('date', [$this, 'dateFilter']),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param string|null $timestamp
     * @param string $fallback
     * @param string $format
     * @return string
     */
    public function dateFilter(?string $timestamp, string $fallback = 'Not set', string $format = 'd/m/Y'): string
    {
        if ($timestamp !== null) {
            return twig_date_format_filter($this->twig, $timestamp, $format);
        }

        return $fallback;
    }
}
```

Adding the extension assuming that `$this->twig` is your Twig Environment:

```
$this->twig->addExtension(new DateWithFallback($this->twig));
```