# Call built-in filter in custom Twig filter

Tags: php, symfony, twig, twig-extension, twig-filter

When setting up a custom Twig filter (see https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html ), how can I call an existing Twig filter in my custom function?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41551944/1668200 suggests `parent::dateFilter($timestamp, $format);` but that isn't working:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "dateFilter" of class "Twig_Extension".

Comment: Just the one?  Twig extensions are just services so you can inject the extension containing dateFilter into your extension and then call dateFilter directly.

Comment: did you read this part carefully - `re-define it in an extension and register it as late as possible (order matters).` ?:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you've linked is actually **incorrect**. The proper way would be like this,

```
class DateEmptyIfNull extends Twig_Extension // or: extends AbstractExtension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new TwigFilter('date', [ $this, 'dateFilter'], ['needs_environment' => true, ]),
        );
    }

    public function dateFilter(Twig_Environment $env, $timestamp, $format = 'F j, Y H:i')
    {
        return $timestamp === null ? '' : twig_date_format_filter($env, $timestamp, $format);
    }

}
```

Comment: You mean it's private cause it's defined outside of the class (and therefore cannot be injected as suggted by Cerad above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54479718/call-built-in-filter-in-custom-twig-filter/54479783?noredirect=1#comment95766639_54479718 )?

Comment: It's defined `private` in the class `Twig_Extension_Core` yes

Comment: Um, it's is defined *outside* of the class (see your link above) - that's why I'm asking. And there's no `private` keyword: `function twig_date_format_filter(Twig_Environment $env, $date, $format = null, $timezone = null)`

Comment: I though that function was defined *inside*  the class.. You could actually call the function then - Sorry for the confusion here :)

Comment: Never mind, thanks for helping! Now I'm getting "Argument 1 passed to App\Twig\AppExtension::date() must be an instance of Twig_Environment, instance of DateTime given". Looks like `['needs_environment' => true]` is not working as expected. Any idea?

Comment: Are you using namespace? If so its gonna be `function dateFilter(\Twig_Environment $env, ...)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187745/discussion-between-thomas-landauer-and-darkbee).

Answer (score 0):

not all twig extensions have their dedicated gloal php function (mainly true for 3rd party twig extensions i think) then the best way if you use the symfony framework is to use autowiring as twig functions are public and can be called via php.

in my case i wanted to create a `asset` function which downloads remote files to the local filesystem and then returns the local path which can be used with the `imagine_filter` filter (which only easily works with local images)

add the twig class to services yaml to allow autowiring if necessary.
`services.yaml`

```yaml
services:
    Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\AssetExtension: '@twig.extension.assets'
```

create your own filter filter/function with a constructor where the other extension can be incjected.

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Twig;

use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\AssetExtension;
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

class ImageAssetExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    private AssetExtension $assetExtension;

    public function __construct(
        AssetExtension $assetExtension,
    ) {
        $this->assetExtension = $assetExtension;
    }

    public function getFunctions(): array
    {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('asset_image', [$this, 'assetImage']),
        ];
    }

    public function assetImage(string $path, string $packageName = null): string
    {
        // do something more here (like downloading a remote asset and returning the local path)
        return $this->assetExtension->getAssetUrl($path, $packageName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The method `dateFilter()` belongs to class `DateEmptyIfNull`. In this case your class must extend this class

Comment: **parent**::dateFilter() cannot belong to this class itself.

Comment: True. If you want call the same class, you will use `self` or `$this` in object context.