# Symfony Flex: Overriding Twig's routing path function

Tags: symfony, symfony4

In Symfony2 it was straightforward to override the RoutingExtension, that I could inject some extra parameters.

I'm using a dynamic domain to route to different parts of my application.

```
{subdomain}.domain.com
```

However, I don't want to have to specify subdomain every time I call path or url in twig.

I could create my own unique filter name, but I'd rather not.

Previously, we could put this in the services.yaml file and it would work.

```
services:
    twig.extension.routing:
        class: AppBundle\Twig\Extension\RoutingExtension
        public: false
        arguments:
          - '@router'
          - '@request_stack'
          - '%domain%'
```

[Symfony2 Twig overriding default path function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23958147/symfony2-twig-overriding-default-path-function)

With Symfony Flex, all I get is `Unable to register extension "App\TwigExtension\TwigRoutingExtension" as it is already registered.`

Answer (score 2):

This is how to override Twig's routing path/url functions in Symfony 5.x using AbstractExtension:

```
namespace App\Twig;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

class MyRoutingExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    public function __construct(
        private UrlGeneratorInterface $generator
    ){}

    public function getFunctions(): array
    {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('path', [$this, 'getPath']),
            new TwigFunction('url', [$this, 'getUrl']),
        ];
    }

    public function getPath(string $name, array $parameters = [], bool $relative = false): string
    {
        return $this->generator->generate($name, $parameters, $relative ? UrlGeneratorInterface::RELATIVE_PATH : UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_PATH);
    }

    public function getUrl(string $name, array $parameters = [], bool $schemeRelative = false): string
    {

        return $this->generator->generate($name, $parameters, $schemeRelative ? UrlGeneratorInterface::NETWORK_PATH : UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In SF4 it's even simpler:

first `composer require symfony/twig-bundle twig/extensions`

Normally autowiring is enable so you can simply do:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Twig;

use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\RoutingExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

class TestExtension extends RoutingExtension
{
    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $generator)
    {
        parent::__construct($generator);
    }

    public function getPath($name, $parameters = array(), $relative = false)
    {
        return parent::getPath($name, $parameters, $relative);
    }
}
```

If you want to setup a service forget about arguments definition it's boring :). Assuming your `%domain%` is available in your parameter do something like this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Twig;

use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\RoutingExtension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBagInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;

class TestExtension extends RoutingExtension
{
    /** @var RouterInterface $router */
    protected $router;

    /** @var RequestStack $stack */
    protected $stack;

    /** @var mixed $domain */
    protected $domain;

    /**
     * TestExtension constructor.
     *
     * @param RouterInterface       $router
     * @param RequestStack          $stack
     * @param ParameterBagInterface $bag
     */
    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router, RequestStack $stack, ParameterBagInterface $bag)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->stack  = $stack;
        $this->domain = $bag->get('domain');
    }


    public function getPath($name, $parameters = array(), $relative = false)
    {
        return parent::getPath($name, $parameters, $relative);
    }
}
```

Comment: Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\RoutingExtension was marked "final" as of SF 4.4 so this does not work anymore as we can't extend it anymore, any idea how to replicate this functionality now ?

Comment: I do not have test, but IMO you should take a tour with https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html

Comment: @Zebratrois, here is the answer how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72365709/2356946